# draw prism dynamically based on distance

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to draw an octagonal prism which also could be oblique and its face shape and height depends on variable and edge lengths.  Where do I start?

Could I use some function for calculating the base B coordinates considering base A is fixed:

[image].

PS: Base A and base B are equals.

Comment: You can start from `THREE.CylinderGeometry()` and `THREE.EdgesGeometry()`.

Comment: I've checked it out and it works as a start but ...how could I modify the edges indepently?

Comment: It's not so clear, what you're asking about. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: I want to design an octogonal prism which one of its bases is fixed and the other depends of the lenght of the edges. Just imagine I have a case a where all the edges have the same length and a case b where each one of its 8 edges have different length (I have the initial coordinates of the vertices of base A). I would like to know that if there's a built in function that can helps me as well as some examples to start working with. I'm absolutely new with this. Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: and what would it looks like, when all vertical edges have different length?

Comment: I see what is the problem, the bases might not be necessarily paralell between them. Does it solve your question? I guess in that case is no longer a prism

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what type of geometry you use. For simplicity, there's an example with a usual geometry (`THREE.CylinderGeometry()`):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 2, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var prismGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 1, 4, 8, 1);
for(let i=0; i< 8;i++){// upper base
  prismGeom.vertices[i].y = 1 + THREE.Math.randFloat(-1, 1);
}
prismGeom.vertices[prismGeom.vertices.length - 2].y = 1 + THREE.Math.randFloat(-1, 1);// center of the upper base
prismGeom.translate(0, 2, 0);

var prism = new THREE.Mesh(prismGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "yellow", wireframe: true}));
scene.add(prism);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

If you want to use a buffer geometry, then you can access its coordinates of vertices with methods of [`THREE.BufferAttibute()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/BufferAttribute), like `.setX`, `.setY`, `.setZ` and so on.

Comment: This is almost perfect but there are two problems:  base B (upper base) vertices are not on the same plane and the cylinder axis angle with the horizontal plane is always 90deg
Could I copy the base A and translate it to a position that depends of the vertical edges length?

Comment: @BRJ It's better to illustrate with a pic of the desired result. So far, it's still not so much clear what you try to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit hard to explain. I've found an example that uses a skinned mesh https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/SkinnedMesh I just have to check if it works using one or two bones. Thanks anyway